# Proof that limits are unique

Tags: calculus, limits, self-learning

I have been working through a few calculus proofs, and to prove that a limit was unique i assumed the fact that if $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ if given any $\epsilon>0$ we have $|c-d|<\epsilon$, then $c=d$.  However, is there an actual proof of this statement, or is this more of an obvious reality?

Comment: It's a theorem that if $a\ge0$ and $a\lt\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then $a=0$

Comment: If $|c-d|=\delta>0$, then it's not true that given any $\epsilon>0$ we have $|c-d|<\epsilon$; take $\epsilon=\delta$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It may be obvious, but in math we like to prove things.

Let $c$ and $d$ be real numbers.  Then $|c-d|\ge0$, so $|c-d|=0$ or $|c-d|>0$.

Assume, with an eye toward contradiction, that $|c-d|>0$,

and for all $\epsilon>0$ we have $|c-d|<\epsilon.$

But taking $\epsilon=|c-d|$, then we would have $\epsilon<\epsilon$, which is a contradiction.

Thus, our assumption that $|c-d|>0$ yielded a contradiction, and it must be that $|c-d|=0$.

Thus, $c=d$.

Comment: Good old contradiction. Thanks this helped a lot

Comment: Never take anything for granted! +1.

Answer (score 5):

Here it is the proof in the context of metric spaces for the sake of curiosity.

**Proposition**

Let $f:(X,d_{X})\to(Y,d_{Y})$ be a function between metric spaces, $x_{0}\in X$ such that $x_{0}$ is an adherent point of $E\subseteq X$ and $L\in Y$. If $f$ converges to $L$ as $x$ approaches $x_{0}$ along $E$, then such limit is unique.

**Proof**

Let us assume that $f$ converges to $L$ and $L'$ as $x$ approaches $x_{0}$ along $E$, and $L \neq L'$.

Then we can take $\varepsilon = d_{Y}(L,L') > 0$.

For such value of $\varepsilon$, there corresponds $\delta^{1}_{\varepsilon} > 0$ and $\delta^{2}_{\varepsilon} > 0$ such that for every $x\in E$ one has that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle d_{X}(x,x_{0}) \leq \delta^{1}_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow d_{Y}(f(x),L) \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{3} = \frac{d_{Y}(L,L')}{3}\\\\
\displaystyle d_{X}(x,x_{0}) \leq \delta^{2}_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow d_{Y}(f(x),L') \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{3} = \frac{d_{Y}(L,L')}{3}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Thus, for such value of $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds $\delta_{\varepsilon} = \min\{\delta^{1}_{\varepsilon},\delta^{2}_{\varepsilon}\}$ s.t. for every $x\in E$ one has that
\begin{align*}
d_{X}(x,x_{0}) \leq \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow d_{Y}(L,L') & \leq d_{Y}(f(x),L) + d_{Y}(f(x),L')\\\\
& \leq \frac{d_{Y}(L,L')}{3} + \frac{d_{Y}(L,L')}{3} = \frac{2d_{Y}(L,L')}{3}\\\\
& \Rightarrow d_{Y}(L,L') \leq 0 \Rightarrow L = L'
\end{align*}
which contradicts our assumption.

Thus, if the limit exists, it is unique.

Hopefully this contributes!

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not provable without really getting deep into the definition/construction of $\mathbb R$. We need the fact that if $a \neq b$, then $|a-b|>0$, and proving that, rather than taking it as an axiom, requires rather complicated mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Limit points are unique in any $T_2$-space (Hausdorff space).

The proof is straightforward, since there are disjoint open sets separating any two distinct points.  Then if there were two different limit points $p,q$ of a sequence $(x_n)$, we reach a contradiction right away, because there are disjoint open sets $U_p,U_q$ with all the elements of the sequence in one, hence not the other, after a certain $n$.

Notes:

- Any metric space is Hausdorff.
- $T_1$ is not enough to ensure unique limit points.
- The cofinite topology on an infinite set is an example of a topology which is $T_1$ but not $T_2$.
- Ultrafilters and nets *do* have unique limits in $T_1$ spaces.

Comment: what is a $T_n$ space, just out of curiosity

Comment: The $T$ comes from a German word meaning "separation", I think.  They're called "separation axioms", or sometimes "Tychonoff axioms", after the mathematician.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Yes, _Trennung_ is German for "separation". But I've always thought that $T$ stood for "Tychonoff" (also "Tihonov" and various other transliterations) and have been proved wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing a fuller answer to this question since other posts on MSE are referred to this post as the definitive answer and certain aspects of this question are unclear.

Assume that $c, d$ are two limits of $f(x)$ as $x \to a$, and that we are working on the real number line.

Then for any $\epsilon>0$ we have:

$0<|x-a|<\delta_1 \Rightarrow  |f(x)-c| < \epsilon$.

$0<|x-a|<\delta_2 \Rightarrow  |f(x)-d| < \epsilon$.

And $\delta=min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ satisfies both conditions.

Then, within $\delta$, contrary to the original post, $|c-d| < 2\epsilon$, not $|c-d|<\epsilon$.

For $|c-d| = |c-f(x)+f(x)-d| \leq |c-f(x)| + |f(x)-d| = |f(x)-c|+|f(x)-d| < 2 \epsilon$

Or, graphically, see the putative limits c, d can space by more than $\epsilon$, up to $2\epsilon$:

[image]

We desire that $c=d$, or that $|c-d|=0$.

For a contradiction, presume $|c-d|>0$

Set $\epsilon_1 = \frac{|c-d|}{2} > 0$, and let the corresponding delta be determined.

Then, by the same triangle inequality above:

$|c-d| =  |c-f(x)+f(x)-d| \leq  |c-f(x)|+|f(x)-d| = |f(x)-c|+|f(x)-d| < 2\epsilon = |c-d|$

And we have $|c-d|<|c-d|$, which is absurd.

Since $|c-d|>0$ is impossible, $|c-d|=0$, and thus $c=d$.