# Show that limits, if they exist, must be unique. In other words, assume $\lim a_{n} = l_{1}$ and $\lim a_{n} = l_{2}$, then $l_{1}=l_{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

I began writing a proof for this, but I am currently stuck. Below is what I have.

> Suppose $\lim a_{n} = l_{1}$ and $\lim a_{n} = l_{2}$. Assume towards
> a contradiction that $l_{1} \neq l_{2}$. For all $\epsilon > 0$, there
> exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $|a_{n}-l_{1}|< \epsilon$ and $|a_{n}-l_{2}|< \epsilon$.
>
> Assume $l_{2}>l_{1}$, so $|l_{2}-l_{1}|>0$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{|l_{2}-l_{1}|}{2}$. We can rewrite $|a_{n}-l_{1}| < \epsilon$ as
> $|a_{n}-l_{1}| < \frac{|l_{2}-l_{1}|}{2}$, and $|a_{n}-l_{2}| < \epsilon$ as $|a_{n}-l_{2}| < \frac{|l_{2}-l_{1}|}{2}$.
> $$|a_{n}-l_{1}|+|a_{n}-l_{2}|<|l_{2}-l_{1}|$$
> We can rearrange this inequality, and use the triangle inequality to simplify.
> $$|l_{1}-a_{n}|+|a_{n}-l_{2}|<|l_{2}-l_{1}|$$
> $$|l_{1}-l_{2}| \leq |l_{2}-l_{1}|$$
> This contradicts our assumption that $l_{1}$ is less than $l_{2}$.

I am not entirely sure if I am going in the right direction with this, or how to continue my argument. Does anyone have any tips on what I should do to either get on the right track, or to finish the argument? Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that limits are unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955577/proof-that-limits-are-unique)

Comment: It somewhat answers the question, but I was looking more for verification that my particular proof is clear, and that it has the right idea. That post is similar in that it helps me finish the proof, but doesn't entirely verify that everything else I wrote is correct. I will be checking there for further clarification, though, so thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have started the proof very neatly.
You should end the proof with $|l_1-l_2| \leq |l_2-a_n|+|a_n-l_1| <|l_2-l_1|$ (for $n>N$) which is a  contradiction.